# WPF app does not start on Windows 7 Embedded - how to trace causes

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7-embedded

I created a simple WPF app from Visual Studio project template (VS 2015). I only changed target framework to .Net 3.5 Client Profile. Then I had to remove the following assembly references Microsoft.CSharp and System.Xaml. Those are not present in .Net 3.5 Client Profile and obviously not needed for running the app.

That mini WPF app just opens a window. It executes normally on regular Windows (I tested Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 7 Enterprise).

But is does not execute on Windows 7 Embedded. There is no window. The process closes immediatley. No error message. Nothing.

I tried on target system:

- Windows EventLog - no entries
- FUSLOGVW.EXE - no errors
- SXSTRACE.EXE - no errors
- DebugView.exe (Sysinternals) with debug build - no debug log messages

This works on target system:

- .Net console apps (running CLR2 and CLR4)
- Windows Forms apps (also with both CLRs)
- DirectX is installed - dxdiag.exe: no problems

What can I do/run to find out what is missing or what goes wrong?

N.B.: The video driver is 'vga' (Standard Windows Video Driver). Does WPF work with 'vga'? The graphics is CPU graphics from Atom D2250. But the drivers from Intel do not work on Windows 7 Embedded.

Comment: I'm assuming that there really is an error log...somewhere.  Would it be possible for you to try running this in debug mode?  Maybe some of your code is getting hit.

Comment: Good idea. I tried DebugView from Sysinternals with a debug build. No debug log message present. I doubt that whole VS 2015 installs on that system. I will give WinDBG a try. But I doubt that WinDBG can break when a .Net exception occurs.

Comment: Is there anything in your event viewer log on the machine that the program fails on?

Comment: There is a pretty big gap between VS 2015 and Windows Embedded Standard 7 (which is from 2011).  Unless you've used WEDU or some other mechanism to update the OS, it is likely that many patches and updates are missing from .Net and maybe other areas.  The VGA drivers should be good enough to display a basic UI, but may fail on some DirectX calls.

Comment: Look at event viewer

Comment: The event log does not tell anything about this issue. We now found out that a simple WPF app works with CLR4. But targeting .Net 3.5 Client (CLR2) still does not work on target system.